Is EFI Simple Filesystem protocol always available in UEFI?
In my UEFI Application, I am using the EFI Simple Filesystem   protocol to read and create files in the ESP partition.
My question is, is this protocol always available? Meaning can I assume this protocol always exists no matter the motherboard model? Meaning can I be sure that the following function never fails in my UEFI Application (during BOOT obviously, so gBS is available) :
  Status = gBS->LocateProtocol(
           &gEfiSimpleFileSystemProtocolGuid, 
           NULL, 
           (VOID**)&simpleFileSystem);

If not, then how can read and create files in my UEFI Application in a way that I can be sure it works in all motherboard models?
I have seen some codes that check for gEfiLoadFile2ProtocolGuid and gEfiLoadFileProtocolGuid, in case gEfiSimpleFileSystemProtocolGuid is not available, is this necessary?
Following is a edk2 sample code that does what I describe:
https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/MdeModulePkg/Core/Dxe/Image/Image.c

Do you mean EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL->DeviceHandle (from the gImageHandle handle) instead of gImageHandle as the first parameter?

gImageHandle is the image handle from the UEFI entry point, i am just wondering that it supports the EFI_SIMPLE_FILE_SYSTEM_PROTOCOL (is this mentioned in the specification?). The usual way would be to get the EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL from gImageHandle and use EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL->DeviceHandle to get the filesystem from which your application was loaded.

@MiSimon I am actually in doubt now, but just to be sure I edited the code and wrote something else that I am sure it works. But will test the previous code and report back if it actually works or was wrong.

@MiSimon Yeah that previous code was incorrect, sorry about that. copied it from a github project I cloned lol.

It will be available on most, if not all, FAT12/16/32 formated partitions, because this a requirement in the specification:
The firmware automatically creates handles for any block device that supports the following file system formats:
• FAT12
• FAT16
• FAT32

But, like most protocols, you can never be sure that it is available on all systems. Even if the driver is loaded there may be no instance of the EFI_SIMPLE_FILE_SYSTEM_PROTOCOL available. An example would be a client without local storage that is booted via PXE.

One question, If I use the above code then use simpleFileSystem->OpenVolume, will it always open the ESP volume? Assume no PXE boot, etc. If not, what other volume could it possible open instead of ESP if not in UEFI shell?

LocateProtocol can return any available instance, it could be even the filesystem of a connected USB stick.

I have seen some codes that check for gEfiLoadFile2ProtocolGuid and gEfiLoadFileProtocolGuid, in case gEfiSimpleFileSystemProtocolGuid is not available, is this necessary? If not, why are they doing it? When would gEfiSimpleFileSystemProtocolGuid not be available?

I habe never used one of the LoadFile protocols myself but i think they can be used to load files (not write!) from various sources (PXE, Filesystems,...). What type of software do you want to write? If you want software that needs local storage, then i would advise to get the DeviceHandle from the LoadedImage protocol and if there is no FileSystem protocol on this handle treat the installation as corrupted.

In some functions I need to read a file from disk only, on others I might write too. But the sample codes I saw got me in doubt, why are they using LoadFile if gEfiSimpleFileSystemProtocolGuid fails? Why would finding gEfiSimpleFileSystemProtocolGuid fail to begin with? https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/MdeModulePkg/Core/Dxe/Image/Image.c

Because this is the base for the BootService LoadImage function. You can read the specification to learn more about the way this function works especially in combination with boot options.

Where can I find the specification for it?  I just want to understand the reasoning behind this implementation, so I can understand whether I need to do the same or not.

sorry for rookie question, but does EFI or edk2  have a official mail list that people like me can ask these questions there, so people who implemented these functions can answer? where should I ask this?

There are some mailinglists for edk2 and one for the UEFI forum. AFAIK the UEFI Forum mailinglist is for bug reports only. If you find a good source information keep us updated.
